# How can I use the command line to combine multiple text files?

Tags: unix, awk

Say I have 3 or more files, is there anyway I can combine these files into a single document? Example below.

**File1**:

> abc123

**File2**:

> 2468, def

**File3**:

> zyx987

I want the outcome to be

**CombinedFile**:

> abc123 2468, def zyx987

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways:

I tested with f1, f2, f3. If the name follows the pattern `fXX`, it can be done like this:

```
$ paste f*
abc123  2468, def       zyx987
$ paste -d' ' f*                     #set space as delimiter 
abc123  2468, def zyx987

$ cat f*
abc123
2468, def
zyx987
```

If you want the output to be a file, just add `> result`

```
$ cat f* > result
$ cat result
abc123
2468, def
zyx987
```

Comment: didn't know about paste. nice :)

Comment: I discovered it not very long ago and was also very surprised :) It is powerful to join files and show in columns.

Comment: +1. You can do `paste -d' ' f1 f2 3` to prevent `paste` from using default `tab` as delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, @JS웃! I also noticed that `paste f*` is also possible. With `-d' '` it makes a very complete answer. Great!

Comment: @fedorqui Yep, I found another nifty coreutil called `pr` which can be used too.

Comment: `pr - convert text files for printing`. Oh, we'll have to try that!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using `pr`.

```
pr -mts' ' f{1,2,3}
```

```
$ head f*
==> f1 <==
abc123

==> f2 <==
2468, def

==> f3 <==
zyx987

$ pr -mts' ' f{1,2,3}
abc123 2468, def zyx987
```